# Java, how to organize WSDL's at project structural level

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, wsdl

How do you organize WSDL based Web Services in Java at project structural level?

Personally I like to store the WSDL in a distinct maven module or project, which is built into a JAR. The resulting JAR contains the WSDL, SEI, client and JAXB classes. Of course the java class generation is automated by the build. Then I can just add the artifact as a dependency to any dependent project. Now, if I need to change the service, I only have to edit the WSDL and build the project. Re-generated java classes are then propagated to all service consumers by the dependency management.

Is this the best way to organize WSDL's? Are there some drawbacks in this approach at certain situations I haven't thought of, or would some other approach provide some additional value?

Comment: There is no best way always look for the most successful. Philosophy aside what you are doing makes perfect sense. Loose coupling is achieved by this as the whole service dependency is now a module in a larger project vs a set of generated artifacts in a project.